# Trying to Validate Emails using C# with a Script in SSIS, but would like to validate only the email column

Tags: c#, csv, ssis

I am using an SSIS script component to validate the CSV file contents. The contents of the CSV file headers with info are: FName, LName, Email, Address, City, State, ZipCode. I would like the regex to validate only the Email column. Is there a way?

```
 [Code]
   public static bool IsValid(string EmailAddress)
    {
        string strPattern = @"^([\w-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]
        {1,3}\.)|(([\w-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$";

        bool bFlag = false;
        System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex regex = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(strPattern);
        System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match match = regex.Match(EmailAddress);
        if (match.Success) bFlag = true;

        return bFlag;
    }
    static void TestSeparatingValidTextData()
    {
        try
        {
            //bool isFirst = true;
            //using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(filePath))
            //{
            //    while (sr.Peek() != -1)
            //    {
            //        if (isFirst)
            //        {
            //            isFirst = false;
            //            continue;
            //        }
            //    }
            //}
            System.IO.StreamReader objReadFile = new 
           System.IO.StreamReader(@"C:\_BISolutions\ClinicDailyData\Bellevue\
            Bellevue_EmailsToValidate\Bellevue_EmailToValidateData.csv");
            System.IO.StreamWriter objWriteValidFile = new
            System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:\_BISolutions\
    ClinicDailyData\Bellevue\Bellevue_ValidEmail\Bellevue_ValidEmailData.csv"
            , false);
            System.IO.StreamWriter objWriteInValidFile = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:\_BISolutions\ClinicDailyData\Bellevue\
             Bellevue_InValidEmail\Bellevue_InValidEmailData.csv", false);
            string strLineData = "";

            while ((strLineData = objReadFile.ReadLine()) != null)
            //&& objReadFile.Peek() != -1)
            {       /*************************/
                    //This first if statement bypasses the first line.
                    //if (isFirst)
                    //{
                    //   isFirst = false;
                    //          continue;
                    //}
                    /*************************/
                if (IsValid(strLineData))
                {
                    objWriteValidFile.WriteLine(strLineData);
                }
                else
                {
                    objWriteInValidFile.WriteLine(strLineData);
                }
            }
            objReadFile.Close();
            objWriteValidFile.Close();
            objWriteInValidFile.Close();
        }
        catch (System.Exception objException)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine(objException.ToString());
            throw objException; //Must add this for the Main method to catch
            this exception. 
        }

    }
    /// <summary>
    /// This method is called when this script task executes in the control
        flow.
    /// Before returning from this method, set the value of Dts.TaskResult to
        indicate success or failure.
    /// To open Help, press F1.
    /// </summary>
    public void Main()
    {
        try
        {

            TestSeparatingValidTextData();
            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
        }
        catch (Exception objException)
        {
            string strMessage = @"On Error, please check the file is in
         C:\_BISolutions\ClinicDailyData\Bellevue\
         Folder";
            Dts.Events.FireError(0, strMessage, objException.ToString()
                                 , string.Empty, 0);
            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Failure;

        }

    }

    #region ScriptResults declaration
    /// <summary>
    /// This enum provides a convenient shorthand within the scope of this
        class for setting the
    /// result of the script.
    /// 
    /// This code was generated automatically.
    /// </summary>
    enum ScriptResults
    {
        Success = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Success,
        Failure = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Failure
    };
    #endregion


 [/Code]
```

I would like to target only one column in the csv file that has a header called email for the RegEx to check (Not all columns). Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're currently passing in the entirely line to your `IsValid` function.  You need to split it and pass in just the entry you want.  For example,

```
var firstLine = objReadFile.ReadLine(); // pop off the header line
objWriteValidFile.WriteLine(firstLine);
objWriteInValidFile.WriteLine(firstLine);
while ((strLineData = objReadFile.ReadLine()) != null)
//&& objReadFile.Peek() != -1)
{       /*************************/
    //This first if statement bypasses the first line.
    //if (isFirst)
        //{
        //   isFirst = false;
        //          continue;
        //}
        /*************************/
    var parts = strLineData.Split(','); // assuming that ',' is your delimiter character
    if (parts.Length >= 2 && IsValid(parts[2]))
    {
        // write to valid file
    }
    else
    {
         // write to invalid file
...
```

Comment: Hi Dan, Yes your are correct and it works awesome! Thank you so much! Wow, yes, you are right by targeting the string position. Thank you once again!

Comment: @ChrisSingleton you have to [accept the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) if it solved your issue

Comment: Hi Yahfoufi, yes you are right and I do accept the answer. In fact, it's brilliant! Thank you guy's for all your help! This really opened my eyes to understanding how to target the column!